# ExternalContext redirect leads to IllegalStateException

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

I am facing a problem that is coming from one of our users. Somehow, the user manages to make multiple redirects with just one click. And by doing this, the redirect method is called multiple times and this leads to the IllegalStateException. I tried to first check if the response is committed and only call the redirect method if the response is not committed. And it works. Just one redirect request instead of all is being sent to the browser. But I was wondering if it's possible to send multiple redirects statements. Is it possible to create a new request with a new response after the old response was committed ?

Here is the working check for the committed redirect:

```
    public static final boolean redirect(String targetPath) {
    try {
        if(!isCommitted()) {
            exContext().redirect(checkAppendContextPath(targetPath));
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (LOG.isErrorEnabled()) {
            LOG.error(String.format(ERROR_REDIRECT, context().getViewRoot().getViewId(), targetPath));
        }
        return false;
    }
}


private static final boolean isCommitted(){
    if(exContext().getResponse() instanceof HttpServletResponse){
        if(((HttpServletResponse) exContext().getResponse()).isCommitted()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, requests cannot be made on the server side. They must originate from the client.

I find it hard to believe that multiple requests are triggered from a single click, unless there is JavaScript involved. If JavaScript is involved, check it for bugs. Else, you could try to prevent multiple clicking at the client side. If you are using PrimeFaces and the redirect is triggered from a `p:commandButton`, you could try using the [PrimeFaces Extensions `CommandButtonSingleClickRenderer`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/renderers/commandButtonSingleClick.jsf).

Comment: The button the user presses is a h:commandLink. When pressed, it calls a method in which the redirect is made. Thank you very much for your answer.